How to extend DIV to occupy its parent DIV's height
I am creating a bootstrap 5 page, but facing a challenge to stretch two child DIVs to the same height as the parent. Can someone help me please?
Here is the HTML:
https://jsfiddle.net/og7pz9sq
In the above fiddle, I am trying to make the light-green and light-yellow DIVs to occupy the while white area. Footer comes just after this white area, and that will always remains at the bottom of the page.
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Bootstrap</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH"
          crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wholepage"
         style="min-height: 90dvh;">

        <div id="header">
            <div class="p-3 bg-primary text-white text-center">
                Bootstrap 5 Page
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="topmenu">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
                <div class="container-fluid">

                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active"
                               href="#">Active</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link"
                               href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <div id="sidebar-and-contents">

            <div class="row">

                <div id="sidebar"
                     class="col-md-auto"
                     style="display: inline;">

                    <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column"
                        style="background-color: rgb(172, 201, 135);">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link"
                               href="#">Link-Left1</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link"
                               href="#">Link-Left2</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div id="content"
                     class="col"
                     style="background-color: rgb(241, 240, 172);">

                    <div>Main area for dynamic contents based on menu selections</div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="footer"
         class="mt-5 p-4 bg-dark text-white text-center">
        <p>Footer</p>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>


The solution is to push away from #wholepage and use flexbox to stretch the descendants.
Somehow:


.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* new */

#wholepage {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#sidebar-and-contents {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: auto;
}

#sidebar-and-contents .row {
  flex: auto;
}

#sidebar {
  display: flex!important;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#sidebar .nav {
  flex:auto;
}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Bootstrap</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH"
          crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wholepage"
         style="min-height: 90dvh;">

        <div id="header">
            <div class="p-3 bg-primary text-white text-center">
                Bootstrap 5 Page
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="topmenu">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
                <div class="container-fluid">

                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active"
                               href="#">Active</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link"
                               href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <div id="sidebar-and-contents">

            <div class="row">

                <div id="sidebar"
                     class="col-md-auto"
                     style="display: inline;">

                    <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column"
                        style="background-color: rgb(172, 201, 135);">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link"
                               href="#">Link-Left1</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link"
                               href="#">Link-Left2</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div id="content"
                     class="col"
                     style="background-color: rgb(241, 240, 172);">

                    <div>Main area for dynamic contents based on menu selections</div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="footer"
         class="mt-5 p-4 bg-dark text-white text-center">
        <p>Footer</p>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>




You can consider using a vertical flex box to fix the footer to the end of the page and make the middle section grow to fill the spaces. d-flex flex-column is added to the two parent container (wholepage and sidebar-and-contents).
Since you are using a media query break point md for a different layout, consider adding flex-column flex-md-row in the sidebar-and-contents container to make sure the content container grows in the correct direction for smaller screen sizes.
See below example: (I've excluded the extra padding and margins for clearer show case.)


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="wholepage" style="min-height: 90dvh;" class="d-flex flex-column">
  <div id="header">
    <div class="p-3 bg-primary text-white text-center">
      Bootstrap 5 Page
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="topmenu">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
      <div class="container-fluid">

        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar-and-contents" class="d-flex flex-column col">
    <div class="row col me-0 flex-column flex-md-row">
      <div id="sidebar" class="col-md-auto pe-0" style="display: inline;">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column" style="background-color: rgb(172, 201, 135);">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link-Left1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link-Left2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="content" class="col" style="background-color: rgb(241, 240, 172);">
        <div>Main area for dynamic contents based on menu selections</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div id="footer" class="p-4 bg-dark text-white text-center">
  <p>Footer</p>
</div>



